# Make binary believe it is in another directory

Tags: bash, filesystems, executable

On a Linux system I have a binary (bin.exe) which needs to read an input file (input.cfg), where the names of other data files (data.txt) are specified. Usually both binary, input file and data files were in the same directory. Now and for organization reasons I need binary file to be in $SOMEPATH/bin and input and data files in $SOMEPATH/input.

I do not know how to do this. If I try

```
$SOMEPATH/bin/bin.exe $SOMEPATH/input/input.cfg
```

I get

```
error, "data.txt" not found
```

One solution would be to include absolute of relative path of "data.txt" in input.cfg, but the binary does not accept this.

I thought about somehow fooling the binary so that it thinks it is in $SOMEPATH/input, so that I just do

```
$SOMEPATH/bin/bin.exe input.cfg
```

and it works, but I do not know whether this is possible. any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(cd $SOMEPATH/input && $SOMEPATH/bin/bin.exe input.cfg)`

This is assuming that the program is relying on the current working directory to find the files.  If the program is trying hard to find them in the same location as the executable, by consulting `/proc/<pid>/exe` for example, then you may be out of luck.

Comment: yes, that did the trick! thanks a lot! last question; output files are produced in $SOMEPATH/input, how can I do so that they are produced instead at other arbitrary directory???

Comment: @flow: Depends - if the program insists on opening its output files in `.` i.e. the current working directory, then you might be out of luck.  Does this mystery `bin.exe` have any documentation, i.e. maybe there are command-line options for specifying the input and output directories, etc.?

Comment: no, unfortunately there is no documentation for the binary (was an old in-house developed program)

Comment: If the binary is complete mystery, you might want to run an `strace` on it to see in what ways it tries to open files. Maybe it checks in places you don't know about, which might work for you.

Comment: i do not think so. this comes from an old C code developed in our group, so should be no rocket-science at all. I think it suits to me if I drop also output files in the same input directory, thanks